# How to choose the longest localized string version?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, localization

So I was thinking if it is possible somehow to choose the longest localized version?

Currently localization:

```
    extension String {
        func localized() -> String {
            let localizedString = NSLocalizedString(self, tableName: "Localizable", bundle: Bundle.main, value: self, comment: "")
            if !localizedString.isEmpty {
                return localizedString
            }
            return "!!\(self)!!"
        }
}
```

The idea is to make it easier for testing, and let's say instead of: `"some.localized.string".localized()` to call `String.pickLongestLocalized(for: "some.localized.string")`

Why? For testing. App is translated to many languages. Going through all of the languages is paintful. Want to see if longest string let's say fits into the button, or into the title, or so on.. This would be TIME SAVER!

- Karma for answers! :D

**Update:**

To make it clearer.. Let's say i have string "continue.button" which is localized to 3 languages.

en translation: "Tap to continue"
de translation: "Tippen Sie, um fortzufahren"
es translation: "Pulse para continuar"

so when I call String.getLongestPossibleString(for: "continue.button") would return de value - `Tippen Sie, um fortzufahren`

Comment: When you say that you "want to see if the longest string fits in a button", do you mean that you want to ensure that the actual localization you have fits into a fixed with (and if not, get a shorter string from a translator), or that the button can adjust to the width of the string properly?

Comment: No no. I just want to see if the current string fits into a button. I want to pick the longest translation out of all languages, that contains let's say most characters.. Also updated the question, so it should be more clear  
@ItaiFerber

Comment: Rather than this, I highly recommend building an extra fake, testing language. You can write a script that finds the longest string for each key in your strings files, and writes a new strings file for the fake language. That way you don't add any complexity to your code.

Comment: It does not look like you tried somehow... where is a problem?

Comment: The longest string depends on a series of factors, like number of characters, type of characters, font used. And deciding at runtime which of those localized strings will take the most amount of screen space would be painfully slow.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a direct answer to your request, but plays more to your stated goal of testing layout for localised strings that are longer than you might expect.

Xcode's run scheme offers a few options to help with debugging localisation. You can access these by going to **Product | Scheme | Edit Scheme...** and selecting **Run**, then **Options**.

[image: Example scheme dialog with localisation options highlighted]

In Localization Debugging, switching on **Show non-localized strings** will uppercase any strings in your views which aren't localised.

Below that is a list of **Application Language** options. If you open this and scroll down to the bottom, you'll see **Double-Length Pseudolanguage** as an option.

This will double up your text items, changing say `Hello World` to `Hello World Hello World` (or, if it's not localised yet and you've got the checkbox enabled, to `HELLO WORLD HELLO WORLD`).

This lets you see the implications of extra long text strings on your layouts. That way, you can validate your layout adjustment choices before your translators even get their hands on your strings files, and without the need to write any extra code.